# PHPUnit cannot find exception class

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, namespaces, phpunit

I am using namespacing in 5.3 and trying to test for an expected exception in PHPUnit with the Symfony2 framework.

I am expecting an exception to be thrown and when I use the

`$this->setExpectedException('ImageResizerException');`

I get the following error:

> PHPUnit 3.7.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> Configuration read from
>   /var/www/branches/3.6.0/api/app/phpunit.xml.dist
>
> .E.................
>
> Time: 1 second, Memory: 18.25Mb
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1)
>   AssetManagerBundle\Tests\Services\ImageResizerTest::testOriginalFile
>   ReflectionException: Class ImageResizerException does not exist
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 19, Assertions: 54, Errors: 1.

I have the following structure:

1. AssetManagerBundle\Services\ImageResizer.php
2. AssetManagerBundle\Services\Exceptions\ImageResizerException.php
3. AssetManagerBundle\Tests\Services\ImageResizerTest.php

My test class:

```
<?php
    namespace AssetManagerBundle\Tests\Services;

    use AssetManagerBundle\Services\ImageResizer;
    use AssetManagerBundle\Services\Exceptions\ImageResizerException;

class ImageResizerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function testOriginalFile()
    {
        $ir = new ImageResizer();
        // test default value
        $this->assertEquals('', $ir->getOriginalFile());

        // test invalid filename
        $this->setExpectedException('ImageResizerException');
        $ir->setOriginalFile('/tmp/test.file');
        $this->assertEquals('/tmp/test.file', $ir->getOriginalFile());


        // test valid filename
        $temp_name  = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'test_'.time());
        $handle     = fopen($temp_name, 'w+');
        fwrite($handle, ' ');
        fclose($handle);

        $ir->setOriginalFile($temp_name);
        $this->assertEquals($temp_name, $ir->getOriginalFile());
    }
    // more code....
}
```

Do I have to do something special for PHPUnit to see my exception class?

PHP Version:

> PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jan 18 2013
>   23:45:59) Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.3.0,
>   Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to fully qualify the exception class along with its namespace. For ex:

```
$this->setExpectedException('\AssetManagerBundle\Services\Exceptions\ImageResizerException');
```

or

```
use AssetManagerBundle\Services\Exceptions\ImageResizerException;
$exceptionClass = get_class(new ImageResizerException(''));
$this->setExpectedException($exceptionClass);
```

Comment: He already used the second solution, it doesn't work. But the first solution does.

Comment: @RezaSanaie for some reason, the second example doesn't work but the first one does

Comment: The only reason I can see why I have to use the FQCN in the `$this->setExpectedException()` call is that this method is defined in the PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase class and so the `use` call is not accessible from that class.

Comment: @Patrick: No, the use class is irrelevant whenever you create a string - even in the same file. See the demo, change as you need: http://eval.in/7883 (but I must criticize my own because I made that explanation first, too)

Comment: I also now updated the second example with a working version (however untested, but it might just make more visible how that works).

Comment: In this case, is \AssetManagerBundle the root of the project, meaning the place where composer.json lives?

Comment: No that'd be the root of your bundle, probably src/*/AssetManagerBundle

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the [FQCN](http://php.net/language.namespaces.dynamic) of the `ImageResizerException` exception:

```
AssetManagerBundle\Services\Exceptions\ImageResizerException
```

The `use` clause on top of the file is for that file only - not for PHPUnit which has it's code in some other files.

*Correction:* It's not (only) that the `use` clause does not work for PHPUnit but because that [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/ReflectionClass) expects a FQCN. That is similar when use a variable (dynamic) class-name in PHP like `new $var`:

```
<?php

namespace Sugar {
    class Exception extends \Exception {}
}
namespace {
    use Sugar\Exception;

    $class = 'Sugar\Exception';
    $e = new $class;
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Output:

```
object(Sugar\Exception)#1 (7) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["code":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["file":protected]=>
  string(45) "/tmp/execpad-7141d0116de7/source-7141d0116de7"
  ["line":protected]=>
  int(10)
  ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["previous":"Exception":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

Demo: http://eval.in/7883

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the class name, use the full namespace of the class instead. Then you will not get the 'class doesn't exist' exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $this->setExpectedException(ImageResizerException::class);
```

is the way to do it using the imported namespace from the `use` statement

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue, but with phpunit, while declaring the @expectedException, it also needed the FQCN.

```
 /**
 * @expectedException \PHPNS\Core\MyCustomException
 */
public function testIfListIsEmpty()
{
    $fab = new PHPList();                         
}
```

Hope that helps someone.